# 403 error HTTP GET request to Jenkins build /api/json

Tags: jenkins, groovy, httpurlconnection

In Jenkins, I am trying to access the change set of a pipeline build by making a HTTP GET call. However I get a 403 error. *Please note* I am able to access this url in the browser so I know it exists and that the url is working.
The url I am trying to access is the "build url" and then appending "/api/json".

```
 try {
      def username = 'username'
      def token = 'token'
      def apiUrl = 'https://<jenkins-root>/job/<job-name>/<build-number>/api/json'

      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(apiUrl).openConnection()
      def encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+token).getBytes("UTF-8"))
      connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")

      def returnedData = connection.inputStream.text
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      println ex
  }
```

When running the above code, I am getting the following error.

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://my-jenkins-build-url/api/json

Since it's 403 error, I can assume I am authenticated but somehow forbidden to access /api/json of the build? Does anyone have a working way of being able to access /api/json of a jenkins build using http call?

Comment: I think it's something in the way you're doing authentication. You're encoding your credentials like Basic ones, but then your authentication header says Bearer. You're also doing a `getBytes`, which seems wrong; the point of encoding something Base64 is to send binary data as text, as you would want to do in an HTTP header.